# Conditional index in 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array, `g`, like so:

```
np.array([
[1 2 3 4], 
[5 6 7 8], 
[9 10 11 12]
])
```

So `g[0]` returns the first row, in other words when I give an index of `0`, I get the first row. When I use an index of 1, I get the second row:

`g[1] = [5 6 7 8]`

and so on.

But I want to return all rows where the index of `g` is NOT a certain value.
Eg. I want to return `g[x] for all x where x != 1`.

I know how to use conditional indexing with 1D arrays, but what about 2D arrays? I'm confused here because I'm not putting conditions on what indices to retrieve according to the values, but I need a condition dependent on the indices themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.arange(len(g)) != 1` to create a boolean index:

```
In [137]: g
Out[137]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

In [138]: g[np.arange(len(g)) != 1]
Out[138]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

If you really want to eliminate just one row, you could, alternatively, use `np.concatenate` to join two basic slices:

```
In [143]: np.concatenate([g[:1], g[2:]])
Out[143]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

For large arrays, the first method appears to be faster, however:

```
In [150]: g2 = np.tile(g, (10000,1))

In [153]: %timeit g2[np.arange(len(g)) != 1]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.9 µs per loop

In [152]: %timeit np.concatenate([g2[:1], g2[2:]])
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: This gives me what I want... but for the faster method, how is it working? I understand what **arange** does. But how is it that the condition you gave works as an index? Doesn't this condition produce an array of indices? But using an array as an index doesn't work, such as this: **g [ 0, 1, 2]**, so how is this working?

Comment: NumPy arrays can be [indexed in a variety of ways](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Indexing), the major three being basic slicing, integer indexing, and boolean indexing. `np.arange(len(g)) != 1` returns a boolean array and hence triggers boolean indexing. Look at what `np.arange(3) != 1` returns if entered in a Python interactive session. You get `array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)`. Each value in the array gets associated with a row of `g`, and every True value causes the associated row to get selected. By the way, `g[[0,2]]` also works; this is an example of integer indexing.

Answer (score 1):

unutbu's answer works, but I find placing the computation in the indices... icky. :/

I would do something like this:

```
rowsidontwant = [1, 3]
listofrows = [ g[i] for i in filter(lambda x: not in rowsidontwant, xrange(len(g))) ]
```

It's a a little more... general. The list of rows may not be what you want, but you can put the data in whatever form you like after that.